# Filter files on a search using a regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, unix

In Bash, I am using an array to store the files I want to copy via regular expressions. Like this:

```
regex_2=(*.awk *.sh *utf8.txt *new.txt)
cp "${regex_2[@]}" $root_dest_dir_2
```

But from files with extension .sh I want to exclude those ending like this:

```
*2016025a.sh *2015039.sh *20150810b.sh
```

So exclude, those ending in .sh preceded by a letter and more than one number or ending in .sh preceded by more than one number.

The directory contains files like these:

```
dev_execute_fromFTP5.sh --> to copy
dev_execute_fromFTP5_2016025a.sh -- to exclude
extrac.sh --> to copy
execute_fromFTP5NT.sh --> to copy
execute_fromFTP5NT_20150226.sh --> to exclude
test5.sh --> to copy
.....
```

Comment: Use find instead. Also what exactly is the difference between files you want to copy and those you don't ?

Comment: Unquoted glob patterns in your array initialization will expand the patterns upfront.

Comment: @anubhava Can you give me an example? I don't know much about unquoted glob patterns.

Comment: Check below good answer from @123 for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gnu find with regex

```
find . -regextype egrep \
       -regex ".*\.(awk|sh|utf8\.txt|new.txt)" \
       ! -regex ".*([0-9][[:alnum:]]).sh" \
       -exec cp {} $root_dest_dir_2 +
```